# Using mailgun on laravel 5.2 - failed to authenticate my sandbox account

Tags: php, laravel, email, laravel-5, mailgun

I'm using Laravel 5.2 that has mailgun integrated. Was trying to send out email via SMTP but couldn't succeed because of the error:

> Failed to authenticate on SMTP server with username
>   "postmaster@sandboxe56d93c917b144e98a4f07d1dbf2683a.mailgun.org" using
>   3 possible authenticators

I'm developing the app on my localhost with virtual host set up (i.e. `app.dev.local`) so I have to use the sandbox account to do all the testing.

These are the laravel's `config/mail.php`:

```
'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'mailgun'),
'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.mailgun.org'),
'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),
'from' => ['address' => null, 'name' => null],
'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),
'username' => 'postmaster@sandboxe56d93c917b144e98a4f07d1dbf2xxxx.mailgun.org',
'password' => 'mypassword'
```

`service.php`'s configurations

```
'mailgun' => [
    'domain' => 'sandboxe56d93c917b144e98a4f07d1dbf2xxxx.mailgun.org',
    'secret' => 'key-63sztbx99h-qdhp7j3-gp6346jsxxxx',
],
```

Everything looks good as I copied directly from my mailgun dashboard for the sandbox account, but the app still can't send out email due to failed authentication.

Does anybody know what is happening here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with port `2525` maybe? You can edit it in the `config/mail.php` file where `587` is currently or through setting it in your `.env` file:

```
MAIL_PORT=2525
```

small correction

Answer (score 0):

Check MAIL_DRIVER, MAIL_HOST, MAIL_PORT values in .env file. If you have this parameters set in .env file, function env call will take the values from that localization.